# How to add row to a dataframe with a pipe using tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Example

Consider this dataframe

```
 abc
 efg
 hij
```

(abc is the column)

I want to convert this into

```
 X
 abc
 efg
 hij
```

Where X is now the main column name and abc is in the values

I tried this

```
 df %>% mutate(X = abc)
```

this turns it into

```
X
efg
hij
```

with abc disappearing

Comment: I am wondering how a dataframe was created where the first row was mistaken as a column name. Did you read the data from a file, perhaps? If this is the case indeed, there might be other solutions available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have multiple columns, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

names(df) %>%
  t %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(names(df)) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  rename_all(~LETTERS[seq_len(ncol(df))])

#    A
#1 abc
#2 efg
#3 hij
```

---

For only single column, it could be simplified a bit.

```
names(df) %>%
  setNames(names(df)) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  rename(X = abc)

#  X    
# <chr>
#1 abc  
#2 efg  
#3 hij
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `imap` to do the appending of column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
imap_dfr(df, ~ c(.y, .x)) %>% 
      rename_all(~ 'X')
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  X    
#  <chr>
#1 abc  
#2 efg  
#3 hij
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(abc = c("efg", "hij")), class = "data.frame", 
     row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```